# Can I make up my own Wondrous Items and Magic Arms/Armor to craft?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting

I have the [Craft Wondrous Item](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/craft-wondrous-item-item-creation---final) and [Craft Magic Arms and Armor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/craft-magic-arms-and-armor-item-creation---final) feats. Am I limited to creating existing items in the books or can I make up my own (within reason)? Because I do have a few ideas…

Answer (score 11):

In principle, there are virtually no limits on what can be crafted by a player with the appropriate feats and sufficient (effective) caster level, time, and money. There are *[guidelines](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Magic-Item-Gold-Piece-Values)* for creating arbitrary magic items which are not explicitly covered by the existing item lists.

The limits that Pathfinder provides are basically maximum bonuses that various items can grant (+5 enhancement to weapons/armor, +10 total bonus to weapons/armor, +6 bonus to abilities, and I think there's a limit to the skill bonus an item can grant, but I can't find it; it may have been a 3.5 limit).

One key thing to remember: the guidelines are ***guidelines***; after using them to price an item, see how powerful similarly-priced items from books available in the campaign are, and adjust the final price or the item's power level (or both) 'til it matches.

## Caveats

There are a few general caveats to keep in mind with regard to crafting feats:

### Time

Crafting requires time. A player who has invested in crafting feats is likely to feel cheated if the campaign doesn't give him time to use those feats (I know I did). If this describes your campaign, consider talking to the GM about swapping the feat out for something that'll be more useful. If there are just one or two specific items that you'd like to make, it may be worth the GP to hire someone to make it rather than burning a feat.

### Space

Crafting most things requires a fair amount of workspace and random, assorted tools (the costs of which are generally negligible, unless they're Masterwork), and potent materials. If the campaign doesn't lend itself to maintaining a base of operation, crafting is going to be difficult or impossible. Scribing Scrolls is the biggest exception to that, as you can generally get away with a folding desk and some pens.

### Material Components

In addition to the material components of any spells which are required to craft the item, crafting needs its own set of materials. Frequently, these are vague and assumed to be relatively easy to obtain (ie., "spend the GP required, and the various bits and bobs are there for your use"). Depending on the particular item, campaign, and GM, finding materials may be a quest in itself. This isn't necessarily a *bad* thing, but it will cut down on the amount of crafting that the character can perform.

## Conclusion

The system-based limits on what can be crafted are pretty minimal. The campaign- and GM-based limits are going to be much more relevant.

Work with your GM to stat and price items before you get too invested in them. Be prepared for the GM to want to bump the price up a bit.

Make sure you've got (or can acquire) the workspace and any special materials before you start crafting: remember, if you start working on a second thing before the first is finished, all of the progress you've made on the first thing is wasted (but, you can pause for as long as you'd like).

Comment: Okay I was thinking about attempting to incorporate an assassin's Hide in plain sight ability into an item with the spells darkness and fog cloud or just darkness. "On command the item releases a shadowy smoke allowing you to blend naturally blend with the darkness, if you're in within 10 ft of a dim light area you may attempt stealth without concealment"

Comment: @ninjahX You should pose a question asking about the requirements for building such an item.

Comment: I tend to agree, but don't be surprised if it winds up being in the neighborhood of a Ring of Invisibility.

Comment: On the workspace concern: "Any place suitable for preparing spells is suitable for making items." ([source](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Magic-Item-Creation)). If you don't have a campsite secure enough for that, then your casters have bigger problems than not being able to use their crafting feats.

Comment: @topquark I'd always read over that line. Good call out.